# Facebook developer alert about privacy policy

Tags: facebook

I have my Facebook app running since March 2017. In the last few weeks I have received 4 emails asking for an update of my privacy policy, once a week on Wednesdays. If I just update the URL to the same link, it looks like solved until the next week, when I receive the same email.

My privacy policy seems to be OK, and I can see Facebook robot accessing it:

2018.01.10.gz:31.13.113.79 - - [10/Jan/2018:08:05:53 +0100] "GET /terms-of-use-and-privacy-policy/rm/1/s_1_3/ HTTP/1.1" 206 36636 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i would file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: What does the debug tool say? See if that lists any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered what was going on... On the first week of January we had to deny access to our server to some IPs because they made lots of requests that affected the server status. Some of those IPs where from Facebook.

Thanks for your help :)